# How to add a validation rule in the scenario?

Tags: validation

I have a checkbox field chk_A on Account.

I want to make sure that at least one of the children Contact's checkbox field chk_B is checked that chk_A can be checked.

Can I loop the children Contacts in the validation formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, validation rules on Account can't reference values on the child Contact records. Formulas can only reference field values on records they look up to, not the other way around.

For a failsafe validation, you would need a trigger on contacts that would update a field (say chk_aContact) on Account, checking whether at least one of the child Contact records has chk_B checked and setting a true/false value. Then your validation rule on the Account object would check whether chk_aContact was true or false. You wouldn't need to add chk_aContact to the Account page layout.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to install [this package](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) written by Andrew Fawcett, you can implement the following strategy:

You can achieve this with a roll-up summary. Create a new field on `Account` called `Checked Contacts`. Create a `Lookup Rollup Summary` to count Contacts with the criterion as `chk_B__c = true`. In your validation rule, you can just check if the count is 0 and the box you want to validate is checked.

**Validation Rule**

```
AND(Checked_Contacts__c = 0, chk_A__c)
```